# cygwin mod-xslt2

Tags: xslt, cygwin, apxs2

I am trying to compile up mod-xslt2 using the cygwin, the mod-xslt2 is using the apache apxs2 program, which is installed within the cygwin environment within the /usr/sbin/ directory but when it comes to finding that program (apxs2) the cygwin ./configure does not appear to "see" it and says it is not there, but when I run the program from the command line within the cygwin interface it works perfectly fine.  Any advice ?

Regards.

Comment: ./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs2 is working